# One more skipping jump discontinuity in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Trying to draw graphs using pgfplots (regarding this library, I am a beginner). I tried to find a solution to my problem (in even offered links), but I was not successful. Is it possible to achieve that when you draw a graph skip discontinuity?
I would like noting that I use pgfplots library only in ConTeXt, but for this need I have prepared an example in LaTeX. 
Thanks for the ideas. Jaroslav

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\AddLabel(#1,#2)#3{\node [align = center] at (axis cs: #1,#2) {#3};}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\function{rad(atan((\x)/(2+\x)))} 
    \def\functionlabel{\arctan{\frac{x}{2+x}}}

\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10, 
        domain=-9.5:9.5,
        ymin=-2,
        ymax=2,
        width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle, 
        axis equal=true,
        xlabel=$x$, 
        ylabel=$y$,          
        samples=600,
        clip=true,
]
\addplot[color=black, line width=1.5pt]{\function};

\AddLabel(6,2.5){$f\!:\ y=\functionlabel$}
\AddLabel(6,2.5){$f\!:\ y=\functionlabel$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're after, one way is to plot two separate lines, one for x < -2, one for x > -2.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\AddLabel(#1,#2)#3{\node [align = center] at (axis cs: #1,#2) {#3};}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\function{rad(atan((\x)/(2+\x)))} 
    \def\functionlabel{\arctan{\frac{x}{2+x}}}

\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10, 
        ymin=-2,
        ymax=2,
        width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle, 
        axis equal=true,
        xlabel=$x$, 
        ylabel=$y$,          
        samples=600,
        clip=true,
]
\addplot[color=black, line width=1.5pt,domain=-9.5:-2]{\function};
\addplot[color=black, line width=1.5pt,domain=-2:9.5]{\function};

\AddLabel(6,2.5){$f\!:\ y=\functionlabel$}
\AddLabel(6,2.5){$f\!:\ y=\functionlabel$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am stupid, I did not invent it myself. I searched for solutions ala Maple (here it comes disable linking discontinuities). Thanks for the good idea. I did not know that  a line can be split into two separate lines. Jaroslav